# Augmented Matrix and Row echelon form

Tags: matrices

For which real numbers s and t does the following linear system have 
(a) no solution,
(b) exactly one solution,
 or (c) infinitely many solutions? Justify your answers.

(s−1)x +(s+3)y + z = 1
 s x + s^2 y + z = 1 
 x + s y + z = t.

i started with making it an augmented matrix:

s-1 s+3 1 1
s   s^2 1 1
1   s   1 t

i know it has to become an reduced row echelon form in order for me to get the two answers, but how do i manipulate the s in such a way to obtain it.

i started by minusing Row 2 - sRow1, where s is the number

then i got

s-1 s+3 1  1
0   0  1-s st
1   s   1  t

how do i continue? help appreciated

Comment: [Here's a page on LaTeX notation.](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: (s-1)  (s+3)  1   1                                                                                                 1         0      0    1-s                                                                                          1        s        1   t